# Expected value of random variable $X$ truncated at $t$.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, density-function

I have a random variable $x$ distributed between $0$ and $1$ with continuous and differentiable density $f(x)$.

I want to express the expected value of $x$ conditional on $x < t$ where $0 < t < 1$ using only $t$, $F(t)$, and $E(X)$, i.e.,

$$E(X|x < t) = \int_0^t\frac{ f(x) x}{F(t)} dx = g(t, F(t), E(X)).$$

I tried using integration by parts

$$
E(X|x < t)
 = \int_0^t\frac{ f(x) x}{F(t)} dx
 = \frac{F(t)\cdot t}{F(t)} - \int_0^t \frac{ F(x)}{F(t)} dx
$$

but I don't know what to do with $\int_0^t \frac{ F(x)}{F(t)} dx$.

I know $E(X) = \int_0^1 1 - F(x) dx$, but I'm not sure if/how I can use that.

I feel like I'm blanking on something simple here.

*Edit*: Corrected the integration by parts.

Comment: Are you able to compute the unconditional expectation? Do you have any more information about $f$ or $F$? If not, I don't think you're able to say much more than what you already have.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist since the OP wants to use $E(X)$, I am assuming there is a way to compute it

Comment: you can pull the F(t) out of the integral (and cancel them in the first term for t > 0), so you get t - 1/F(t)*int(F(x)dx,x=0..t).  But I'm not sure how much that helps

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I think you are right, there is not enough information. There are several densities with the same $E(X)$, $t$ and $F(t)$, for example with $t=1/2$, $E(X)=1/2$ and $F(t)=1/2$. Any density symmetric around $1/2$ should have these values, but they would have different $E(X|x<t$, e.g., uniform, u-shaped and bell-shaped.

Comment: @BJU Yes, exactly! I was in the middle of writing my answer when you commented.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You can have a look at a family of my CDFs [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efk1pmc9aa).

This is unfortunately not possible. Consider for example $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and let $Y$ have the following CDF:
$$F_Y(x)=\frac{g\left(\frac14+\frac x2\right)}{g\left(\frac34\right)}+(1-x),$$
where $$g(x)=\ln(x)-\ln(1-x).$$

We have $\int_0^1 F_X = \frac12$ and
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 F_Y&=\frac12+\frac1{g\left(\frac34\right)}\int_0^1 g\left(\frac14+\frac x2\right)\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\frac12+\frac2{g\left(\frac34\right)}\int_{\frac14}^{\frac34} g(y)\,\mathrm dy
\\&=\frac12
\end{split}
since $g(x+\frac12)=-g(-x+\frac12)$.

Hence, $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY$. Also, it is easy to check that $F_Y\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12=F_X\left(\frac12\right)$.

However, since $F_Y(x)>F_X(x)$ (see footnote) for $0<x<\frac12$, we have $\mathbb E(X\mid X<\frac12)>\mathbb E(Y\mid Y<\frac12)$ so there is no way to express the conditional expectation based solely on $t, \mathbb EX$ and $F(t)$.

Plot of $\color{red}{F_X}$ and $\color{green}{F_Y}$:

[image]

Footnote: We have
$$F_Y(x)-F_X(x)=1-2x+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+2x}{3-2x}\right)}{\ln(3)}$$
which is clearly positive on $[0,0.5]$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't enough information.

Consider the uniform distribution, and the triangular distribution whose peak is at $1/2$, both on $[0,1]$ They both have mean equal to $1/2$, and have $F(t) = 1/2$ at $t=1/2$.

Thus, you cannot write $E(X\mid X<t)$ solely as a function of the numbers $E(X)$, $F(t)$ and $t$.

Comment: I would've gone for this but the PDF of the triang. distrib. is not differentiable. But I like it :D

Comment: @Maximilian yes, I was wondering why you hadn't gone with the triangular distribution!

Comment: Well I read "...with continuous and differentiable density $f(x)$" so I made it a challenge to find the function that I was visualising in my head :D

Comment: @Maximilian well you read the question much more carefully than I did then :)